# How to throw out of then-catch block?

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

I am currently figuring out how to throw an Exception out of a then catch block. I want to get into the catch that is inside the `errorHandler()` function.

```js
const errorHandler = function () {
  try {
    thisFunctionReturnsAnError().then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); //How to trigger this?
  }
};

const thisFunctionReturnsAnError = function () {
  return3()
    .then(value => {
      throw new Error('This is the error message.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      //return Promise.reject('this will get rejected');
      throw err;
      //this one should somehow got to the catch that is located in the errorHandler() function. How to do this?
      //I know that this 'err' will be in the next catch block that is written here. This is not what i want.
    });
};

const return3 = async function () {
  return 3;
};

errorHandler();
```

I searched a while on stackoverflow but nothing helped me. I am sure that this question got asked often but I could not find the answer, sorry for that.

EDIT:
added here another version of the code but it still does not work

```js
const errorHandler = async function () {
  try {
    thisFunctionReturnsAnError()
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  } catch (e) {
    //console.log(e); //How to trigger this?
  }
};

const thisFunctionReturnsAnError = function () {
  return3()
    .then(value => {
      throw new Error('This is the error message.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(`Message is: ${err}`);
    });
};

const return3 = async function () {
  return 3;
};

errorHandler();
```

I will get the following error message:
**Uncaught (in promise) Message is: Error: This is the error message.**

Comment: Error handling for Async method needs to be handled different than the traditional way, Below link could be useful for you.
Ref: https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly this does not answer my question. The content in your given link does not handle my case. I throw in the .catch() function. This is not handled on the website you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't be executed, because "thisFunctionReturnsAnError" is not returning an Promise. That means that you can't call "then" on the return value.

```
    thisFunctionReturnsAnError().then(response => { // will not work
```

Why not always use a promise?

```js
const errorHandler = function () {
  thisFunctionReturnsAnError()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('errorHandler: Handle the error.');
    });
};

const thisFunctionReturnsAnError = function () {
  return return_Three()
    .then((value) => {
      throw new Error('This is the error message.');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //return Promise.reject('this will get rejected');
      throw err;
      //this one should somehow got to the catch that is located in the errorHandler() function. How to do this?
      //I know that this 'err' will be in the next catch block that is written here. This is not what i want.
    });
};

const return_Three = async function () {
  return 3;
};

errorHandler();

/*****JUST ANOTHER SYNTAX*******/
const secondErrorHandler = async function () {
  try {
    await thisFunctionReturnsAnError();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('secondErrorHandler: Handle the error.');
  }
};

secondErrorHandler();
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But why is it necessary to write `return return_Three()` instead of `return_Three()` ?

Comment: It is necessary because you try to react on it. > thisFunctionReturnsAnError().   Otherwise this function online returns "void".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle promise rejections with synchronous `try`/`catch`. Don't use it, use the promise `.catch()` method like in your `thisFunctionReturnsAnError` function.

You can handle promise rejections with `try`/`catch` when using `async`/`await` syntax (which you already do, albeit unnecessarily, in `return3`):

```
async function errorHandler() { /*
^^^^^ */
  try {
    const response = await thisFunctionReturnsAnError();
//                   ^^^^^
    console.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // works
  }
}
```